# Are JaxB Unmarshaller, SchemaFactory and Schema immutable?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following code in a loop:

```
final Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
final SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
final URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("/schema/MySchema_1.0.xsd");
final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(resource);
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
final JAXBElement<MyObject> unmarshal = (JAXBElement<MyObject>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

Apart from the actual unmarshalling, can the other lines be moved outside of the loop?

Are `Unmarshaller`, `SchemaFactory` and `Schema` immutable and/or threadsafe? (at the moment this code only processes one stream at a time, but parallel execution is possible in the future).